# Why Mathematica is incapable doing fast symbolic integrations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to calculate this symbolic integration below, but kernel has still been running for a long time and it has not come up with a solution yet. Could you have a look at it, I was wondering if there is an alternative way of doing this..

```
y[t_] := 1/2*Integrate[1 - ((h + (1 - b)*t)/(a + k*(x - c)^2))^2, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {0 < b < 1, a > 0, c \[Element] Reals}] - M*g
```

Thanks for the comments and/or answers.

Comment: Two common reasons Mathematica can't do an integration (1) there is no closed form solution to the problem (2) all the variables have not been suitably constrained.

Comment: @bill s , But if we change the variable `x-c = sqrt[a/k]*Tan[\phi]` , we can find the solution by hand. However, I want to solve this integration using Mathematica.

Comment: a should eventually be `a = h-b*t - (k-t)^2/(4*k)` and `c = (k-t)/(2*k)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need another assumption: `k>0`. Further, to avoid to recompute the integral each time when you call your function `y`, I should use `Set` (=) instead of `SetDelayed` (:=):

```
y[t_] =1/2*Integrate[1-((h+(1-b)*t)/(a+k*(x-c)^2))^2,{x,0,1},
  Assumptions->{0<b<1,a>0,c\[Element]Reals, k>0}] - M*g
```

This produces a moderate long output in about 6 seconds.

Comment: Yes, thank you @Fred Simons , this was very helpful.